# Android tool MonkeyImage does not support jpeg?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

i have written a script in python using monkeyrunner:

```
image=device.takeSnapshot()
image.writeToFile('filename.jpg','jpg')
```

but i have got a null image like this:

```
-rw-rw-r-- owner group 0 Apr 14 21:56 filename.jpg
```

when i write

```
image.writeToFile('filename.png','png')
```

it worked well.I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, `adbclient` the communication method used by [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki) to interact with Android devices and emulators, supports saving images as JPEG.

The basic script to do it would be really simple

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from com.dtmilano.android.adb.adbclient import AdbClient

AdbClient('.*').takeSnapshot().save('/tmp/image.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

If you are interested in knowing more about `adbclient`, why it can save images as JPEG or the driving forces behind it creation, there is an article that could help you understand, [adbclient: under the hood of AndroidViewClient/culebra](http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2014/03/adbclient-under-hood-of.html).